# Sum function in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum

I am new to VBA coding in excel, and i have attempted to setup a Loop that checks out if different sums add up i a budget excel standard excel sheet from work, as people often overwrite the formulas and skip steps, and thereby mess up the system when transferring to our accounting system.

I however have a challenge with the the sum of a range and comparing it to the existing sum in the sheet. My code looks like this in the loop:

```
'lokaler, rengøring
Dim lok As Double
Dim loksum As Double
Dim lokdif As Double
loksum = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(38, i), Cells(41, i)))
lok = Cells(37, i)
lokdif = lok - loksum


If lokdif <> 0 Then
    Cells(37, i).Select
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
    Else
    Cells(33, i).Select
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
End If
```

The code runs through the worhsheet, but lokdif seems to never be <> 0, even if i change values to force a mistake. I think there is a problem with the application.sum , but i have not been able to find any solution. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would use the Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum , also explicitly state the sheet being worked with I.e. not just Range or Cells. Avoid .Select and have Cells(37,i) in a variable. Nothing immediate else I can see except is 0 recognised as double or does it need to be cast as double?

Comment: Thank you QHarr - works perfectly now!

Comment: In what worksheet is Cells(37, i) referring to? If there is more than one sheet, the default is ActiveSheet, which may or may not be the worksheet you want to check

Comment: In this case the activesheet default is ok, as it is a function to highligt mistakes, as the user is looking at the sheet.

Comment: You mention a loop, but can't see one in your code, where do you get the values for i?

Comment: I just copied a part of the loop as it is quite long, and the problem did not seem to be in the loop. The loop says: For i = 4 To 150
Columns(i).Select - and the ends with a: next i after the if statement